# Why does it error when I use List Box dot Contains?

Tags: vb.net

So when I use this code:

```
    If lbMembers.Contains(lbStudents.SelectedItem) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't add the same person twice")
    End If
```

It doesn't say there's an error. However, when I start the application it crashes the moment I try to use it and gives me this message:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control

I've tried everything I could think of but I can't figure it out.

Please, help a newbie out!

Comment: Where in the intellisense list did `Contains` show up when you typed that dot?

Answer (score 4):

Because a ListBox is a control, not a collection of things.  You need to use `lbMembers.Items.Contains`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.contains?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_ObjectCollection_Contains_System_Object_

Comment: When I do that the error message appears anytime I transfer an item to the other listbox, heres the full code for more context

Comment: Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim selectedItems = (From i In lbStudents.SelectedItems).ToArray()

Comment: For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
            lbMembers.Items.Add(selectedItem)
        Next
        If Me.lbStudents.SelectedIndex <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Select someone")
        End If

Comment: If lbMembers.Contains(lbStudents.SelectedItem) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Can't add the same person twice")
        End If

Comment: I can't read that.  If you need to clarify something, do it in the body of your question so people don't have to go hunting for clarifications that should rightfully be part of your question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. All you had to do is add Items. A ListBox can't contain anything but .Items

```
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(ListBox2.SelectedItem) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can't add the same person twice")
End If
```